# NSMutableDictionary setObjetct forKey id NSString

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa

Frankly, it is rather a detail question. 
Apples documentation of NSMutableDictionary https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html states:

```
setObject:forKey:
Adds a given key-value pair to the dictionary.
- (void)setObject:(id)anObject forKey:(id)aKey
```

According to that the parameter `forKey` accepts any object. However, when I try to pass an NSNumber `Incompatible pointer types sending 'NSNumber *' to parameter of type 'NSString *'`
Aparently some NSString only is accepted as key.

For the time beeing I will convert my number to a string. In the end it is just a key. But does anybody know who is right? The documentation or the compiler?

Comment: Could you share a small code sample that reproduces this problem ? `NSNumber` _can_ be used as the key.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You *shouldn't* get that warning when using `setObject:forKey:`. However, you *will* get that warning when using the similarly-named `setValue:forKey:`. The latter, while it appears similar in name, is part of the key-value coding system and thus only accepts an `NSString` as the key.

Here's a [sample program](https://gist.github.com/48e3ad94ac3a7fdc2627) to demonstrate the difference.

Comment: That's it. I have overlooked that I'd picked the wrong mehtod although I was aware of the difference. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Apple's documentation is right, maybe you were confusing the method `setObject forKey` with the `setValue forKey` as @mipadi said.

Answer (score 0):

this works fine:

```
 [someMutableDictionary setObject:@"a string" forKey:[NSNumber numberWithInt:1]];
```

what does your code look like?